# bash history truncated after sudo su

Tags: bash, linux-mint, command-history, gnome-terminal

I modified the .bashrc file to make the .bash_history file with "infinite" size and it's working only when I `sudo su` to use root on terminal, the history file is truncated back to the default 2000 line size. Any suggestions to solve this, please?

from my **.bashrc** file :

```
export HISTFILESIZE=
export HISTSIZE=
export HISTFILE=~/.bash_infinite_history
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Answer (score 1):

My bash version says that the defaults for HISTFILESIZE and HISTSIZE are 500, so something in root's .bashrc or .bash_profile is resetting them to 2000. Since you su'd to root, a new shell is launched (presumably bash). You'll either need to update root's .bashrc settings or manually enter those variables & values into the new shell.

Comment: I found the culprit : its /etc/bash.bashrc , I rcommented out `HISTFILESIZE` and `HISTSIZE` and now its working  fine